# Why "href" and "th:href" exist at the same time?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am reading a page using Thymeleaf.

In "Edit page", there is a "Back" button for going back to "User List Page". The strange thing for me is this button has "href" and "th:href" at the same time. 
[image detail of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN9LT.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>user</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}"></link>
</head>
<body class="container">
<br/>
<h1>修改用户</h1>
<br/><br/>
<div class="with:80%">
    <form class="form-horizontal"   th:action="@{/edit}" th:object="${user}"  method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="*{id}" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="userName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">userName</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName"  id="userName" th:value="*{userName}" placeholder="userName"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"  th:value="*{password}" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 control-label">age</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age"  id="age" th:value="*{age}" placeholder="age"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info" />
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <a href="/toAdd" th:href="@{/list}" class="btn btn-info">Back</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is obvious that "th:href" is for going back. Is there any opition on what is the function of the atrribute "href"?

Comment: Read the docs: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

Comment: @LGSon I have read the docs recommended. But it is not corresponding to my problem. I know how “th:href" work and its function. I have reedited my post, making it more clear and specific. Perhaps you can reread it.

Comment: If you read the docs (link I provided) properly, you'll understand what `th:href` is for. No need for me to write it all over. Have a look at paragraph _2. Context-relative URLs_.

Comment: @LGSon I have read the paragraph 2 again and properly I guess. But ike what I said already in last comment, I can totaly understand what **th:href** is for. The point you pointed out is really not my problem. My problem is: In `<a href="/toAdd" th:href="@{/list}" class="btn btn-info">Back</a>`, I don't know what **href="/toAdd"** is for. That is my problem. And I don't know if I am clear this time. Hope to have your opinion on it

Comment: And neither do I (know what `/toAdd` is/means, other than being a part of an `url` of course). If you didn't add it yourself, then you need to go back to where you got that code piece in the first place, and check what they/it said it is. And since you understand the logic behind the two, it will be simple to fix it.

Comment: @Martin521Wang What are you actually asking? Are you wondering "why there is two href attributes at the same time?" If so one (just href) is acting like a static placeholder; in which you can see your page style without running a server container or similar. In your case your href value is obviously different than your th:href value which is not important when you run your code (since only th:href is evaluated)

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for your opinion, which has exactly resolve my problem. As **Ahmet** said, I guess the **href** attribute is a logical bug and I have tried to contact the author of that code piece.

Answer (score 1):

ThymeLeaf is designed to use the same file for both as prototype you can view in your browser as well as a working template file. What this means in practice is that if you want, you can open the template file in a browser without actually running it and it still looks okay.  For example, in this code:

```
<a href="/toAdd" th:href="@{/list}" class="btn btn-info">Back</a>
```

If you open the file directly in a browser, the browser will ignore the `th:href` (because it doesn't know what to do with it) and instead use `href="/toAdd"`.  However, when you run it through the templating engine on a server, `href="/toAdd"` is replaced with the result of the dynamic expression `th:href="@{/list}"`.

This is more easily shown with a table.  Like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>IN STOCK</th>
  </tr>
  <tr th:each="prod : ${prods}" th:class="${prodStat.odd}? 'odd'">
    <td th:text="${prod.name}">Onions</td>
    <td th:text="${prod.price}">2.41</td>
    <td th:text="${prod.inStock}? #{true} : #{false}">yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When you open that in a browser, you'll see a table with a single row (Onions, 2.41, yes).  But when you run it through the server, the actual content of the table is replaced with whatever data exists in the `${prods}` variable.

Comment: That is really a fresh knowledge which really show me a deeper insight about Thymleaf. Thanks a lot