# Why does linking libraries from thymyleaf fragments need double linking?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have a question about linking libraries.

I usually do it this way:

```
<link href="sidebar/common/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but now I wanted to start using *thymeleaf* fragments. Each tutorial I've seen about linking libraries using *thymeleaf* fragments looks the same. **Why people always put "double" linking if it isn't necessery?** (my code above works well and i don't need to link this libraries second time using *thymeleaf*)

For example my code above in every tutorial will look:

```
<link href="sidebar/common/style.css"
      th:href="@{sidebar/common/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" >
```

**Can anyone explain what is the correct and recommended way to link these libraries?** 
What about javascript and fontawesome linking?

I am sorry for this kind of question but I am just starting with thymeleaf and it gives me no peace. I hope that this will not upset the admin and a good answer will also be useful to others

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615323/why-href-and-thhref-exist-at-the-same-time/54638534#54638534 -- really, there is no reason to have both links unless you wish to prototype your files in a browser (without evalutating the thymeleaf).  I personally just use `th:href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use both of the linking types simultaneously, unless you really need it for example for quick prototyping.

`href="sidebar/common/style.css"` is being used only when you open your template directly in the browser. It is a standard HTML tag which will be processed by your browser, while th:href will be ignored.

Whereas `th:href="@{sidebar/common/style.css}` will be processed by the template engine and `href` will be substituted by Thymeleaf.

Similarly, Thymeleaf will override the content of any HTML tag, then there is a `th:text` attribute present, for example:

```
<p th:text="${variableName}">That text will be overriden by variableName value</p>
```