# thymeleaf defference action and th:Action?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

when attributes are used together with attribute of existing normal attribute and when used alone.

What's the difference..?

For example

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/seedstartertermng}" th:object="${seedStarter}" method="post">

<form th:action="@{/seedstartertermng}" th:object="${seedStarter}" method="post">
```

above, when using action attribute with th:action,

Why do i have to write it twice similar attribute?

can't i use th:action alone?

Does second case using only th:action perform the same function as first case?

ps. Additionally, what is the role of the "#" character in the first sentence..?

Comment: You don't have to you can write them both. If you want to test/show the forms you need an empty `action` which is what the `#` does. The `th:action` takes into account the context it runs in and will generate the proper URL to submit to (instead of you writing it manually).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks! so, Are you saying that this syntax is correct if the appropriate action is required in the form?<form th:action="@{/seedstartertermng}" th:object="${seedStarter}" method="post"> Is this syntax correct? ( not using normal action tag, cause using th:action

Comment: i think th:action tag is defined to put an appropriate value in the action tag, but I wonder if an appropriate value is put in even if the action tag does not exist.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `action` is or isn't there if you use `th:Action`.

Comment: See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615323/why-href-and-thhref-exist-at-the-same-time/54638534#54638534 -- you don't need `action` in this case, but it allows you to do stuff with natural templating.